# Creating File in Drag and Drop Enabled File Cabinet in Netsuite using Rest API from Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, netsuite, netsuite-rest-api, salesforce-rest-api

I already have a rest api built between Salesforce and Netsuite to create sales orders in Netsuite from Salesforce.

I would like to do the same but with creating a file in Netsuite from Salesforce. I'm not a Netsuite expert so this is where I'm running into issues.

For the sales order I'm using this endpoint: https://[my sandbox account id].suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/salesOrder/[sales order id]

and I'm using Oauth 1.0 and HMAC-SHA256

Does anyone know if and how I can do the same with files, and specifically add them to a specific folder in the drag and drop enabled file cabinet (I'm also not sure how to find the folder id, any insight on that would be great).

Trying to figure out to correct endpoint to do this with testing in Postman, either to create a new file or to query one.

Or will I have to use SOAP for this? Wondering if I can get away with rest api.

I'm also trying to see if I don't have to use a suitelet script since my strength is within salesforce and I'm looking to code this entirely in Apex.

Thank you!

I found this documentation, but having trouble understanding it:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/content-cloud/rest-api-documents/rest-endpoints.html

Was looking at trying to query a file but wasn't sure which action was appropriate and how the endpoint should be constructed